# Adjency list from table of paths

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that stores employees and their departments. The departments represents as full path in the organization hierarchy:

Table name: **SourceTable**

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
  Employee              Department
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
   John D.              Organization/Department1/Department2
   Alexey N.            Organization/Department1/Deparment2/Department3
   Alan Z.              Organization/Department1
   Peter P.             Organization/Department4
   Zara N.              Organization/Department4/Department5
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I need to normalize this table and create two new as following:

Table: **Employees**

```
|--------------------------------------------|
  Name                 DepartmentId
|--------------------------------------------|
  John D.              3
  Alexey N.            4
  Alan Z.              2
  Peter P.             5
  Zara N.              6
```

|--------------------------------------------|

Table name: **Departments**

```
|--------------------------------------------|
  Id           ParentId          Name
|--------------------------------------------|
  1               null           Organization
  2               1              Department1
  3               2              Department2
  4               3              Department3
  5               1              Department4
  6               5              Department5
|-------------------------------------------|
```

What query(s) should i use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No single query here.

Let's create the setup first:

```
declare @t table (Employee varchar(10), Department varchar(100))
insert @t values
(   'John D.'   ,           'Organization/Department1/Department2'),
(   'Alexey N.' ,           'Organization/Department1/Department2/Department3'),
(   'Alan Z.'   ,           'Organization/Department1'),
(   'Peter P.'  ,           'Organization/Department4'),
(   'Zara N.'   ,           'Organization/Department4/Department5')

declare @d table (Id int identity(1,1), ParentId int, Name varchar(20))

declare @e table (Name varchar(10), DepartmentId int)
```

We also need a function to parse the string reporesenting path (we need numbers table here, pls search the SO for instructions how to create and populate one):

```
create function dbo.splitstrings_numbers
(
    @list       nvarchar(max),
    @delimiter  nvarchar(5)
)
returns table
with schemabinding
as
    return
    (
        select number, item = substring(@list, number,
            charindex(@delimiter, @list + @delimiter, number) - number)
        from dbo.numbers
        where number <= convert(int, len(@list))
            and substring(@delimiter + @list, number, len(@delimiter)) = @delimiter
    );
```

Now we can parse the path (into a temp table, we reuse it):

```
select *, 0 as rn 
into #t 
from @t
outer apply [dbo].[splitstrings_numbers] (department, '/')

create index IX__t__employee_number on #t (employee, number)

;with x as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by employee order by number desc) rn2
    from #t
)
update x set rn = rn2
```

It's easy from now on :)

```
insert @d (name)
select distinct item from #t


;with x as (
    select d.parentid, d3.id as new_parentid
    from @d d 
    join (select distinct item, lag(item) over(partition by employee order by rn desc) as parent from #t) d2 on d2.item = d.name
    join @d d3 on d2.parent = d3.name
)
update x set parentid = new_parentid

insert @e
select #t.employee, d.id departmentid
from #t
join @d d on #t.item = d.name and #t.rn = 1

select * from @d
select * from @e
```

Comment: Dean, thank you for your time. It's look like working fine but i'm not satisfied with performance. In my enviroment for 7000 employees this solution takes about 25 minutes. Could you suggest performance tuning?

Comment: Did you identify which part runs slowly? If it's the "select into #t" part, I'd suggest adding the row_number *after* the initial load of the temp table, and indexing on (employee, number). If it's the update CTE, then index the over clause, on (employee, rn). Otherwise, can you shere the exec plan perhaps?

Comment: It's look like the problem is with this part:
select *, row_number() over (partition by employee order by number desc) rn
into #t 
from @t
outer apply [dbo].[splitstrings_numbers] (department, '/')

Comment: Analizing results of department table i have found another bug. The solution is not correctly works if some employees in the source table has the same full name.

Comment: Splitting the path is a costly operation, but it can't be avoided. I've edited the code somehow, see if this performs better. WRT the non-unique employees, there has to be something to uniquely identify rows. Is there such a column in the SourceTable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming department names are unique across entire organization(s).
Sample data

```
select Employee, Department
into #sample_data
from (
    values
         ('John D.  ','Organization/Department1/Department2'),
         ('Alexey N.','Organization/Department1/Department2/Department3'),
         ('Alan Z.  ','Organization/Department1'),
         ('Peter P. ','Organization/Department4'),
         ('Zara N.  ','Organization/Department4/Department5')
    ) t(Employee, Department);
```

Splitting paths using Jeff Moden's `DelimitedSplit8K` (or any other splitter you choose). It produces numbered list of items.

```
select Department as path, d.*
into #tmp
from #sample_data
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(Department,'/') d;
```

Departments

```
select Department = item,
    id = row_number() over (order by item),
    parent_id=null
into #deps
from (
    select distinct item  
    from #tmp) t;
```

Employees with dept id

```
select Employee, 
   id = row_number() over (order by Employee),
   dep_id = d.id
into #emps
from #sample_data sd
join #deps d on sd.department like '%'+d.Department;
```

Now adjency

```
update d
set parent_id = d2.id
from #deps d
join (
    select distinct child=t1.Item, parent=t2.item 
    from #tmp t1 
    join #tmp t2 on t1.path = t2.path and t1.ItemNumber-1 = t2.ItemNumber
    ) adj
on d.Department = adj.child
join #deps d2 on adj.parent = d2.Department;
```

Check it

```
select * from #deps;
select * from #emps;
```

**EDIT**

If departments are not unique, keep their paths till the adjency is established. Here `DelimitedSplit8KWithPath`0 is aforesaid `DelimitedSplit8K` returning the parent path as well, just one line added so the final SELECT is

```
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1),
        Parent     = LEFT(@pString, CASE WHEN l.N1>1 THEN l.N1-2 ELSE 0 END)
   FROM cteLen l
```

And the workflow is essentially the same, queries are a bit shorter

-- All departments including those with no employees currently
select distinct Department = CASE WHEN len(parent)> 0 THEN parent +'/' ELSE ''END + item
      , d.parent
      , item
into #tmp
from #sample_data
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8KWithPath(Department,'/') d;

--Departments

select Department,
    id = row_number() over (order by Department),
    parent_id=null
into #deps
from #tmp

--Employees with dept id

select Employee, 
   id = row_number() over (order by Employee),
   dep_id = d.id
into #emps
from #sample_data sd
join #deps d on sd.department = d.Department;

--Now adjency

update d
set parent_id = d2.id
 , department = item
from #deps d
join #tmp adj on d.Department = adj.Department
join #deps d2 on adj.parent = d2.Department;

select * from #deps;
select * from #emps;

Comment: Serg, thank you for your time. Unfortuantly department names are not unique.